# Fill Column of existing data table

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datacolumn

I have a table like this

col1       col2       col3

a           b
c           d

i want to fill the 3rd columns

Can any one help me.

Comment: Which database? Do you need to do that in code inside an application? Or is just one time maintenance work?

Comment: I need to do that inside an application

Answer (score 0):

I have filled the datatable using `LoadOption.Upsert`
Here `strQuery` get the data to fill with the existing datatable, `dt` is existing datatable. specify a primary key in datatable to avoid duplicates.

`Public Shared Function ExecuteDataTable(ByVal strQuery As String, ByRef dt As DataTable)`

`Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
        Dim con As New MySqlConnection
        con = GetFinalyMySqlConnection()
        Try
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.CommandType = Text
            cmd.CommandText = strQuery
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
            Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            da.FillLoadOption = LoadOption.Upsert`

```
        da.Fill(dt)
        dt.AcceptChanges()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    Finally
        CloseConnection(con)
    End Try
    Return dt
End Function`
```